# how to grab my wordpress posts from different subdomain?

Tags: wordpress

I have my blog on blog.mydomain.com and I am realizing that I want to be able to grab entries and put in a section on my www.mydomain.com

Is there a way to do that?  Perhaps a widget or plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help you. : [Display Wordpress content from Outside Wordpress](http://www.voodish.co.uk/articles/display-wordpress-content-from-outside-wordpress/)